# Correct Update with Count Syntax

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm trying to update multiple keyed records with a single query, but I don't know the correct syntax.

Here's my attempt:

```
UPDATE hL
SET hL.[QUANTITY_COMPLETED] = (SELECT COUNT([SERIAL_NUMBER]) 
                               FROM [dbo].[ORDER_ITEMS] oO
                               INNER JOIN [dbo].[JOB_HISTORY] jH ON jH.[ORDER_NUMBER] = Oo.[ORDER_NUMBER]
                               INNER JOIN [dbo].[JOB_HISTORY_LINE] hL ON hL.[LINE_NUMBER] = oO.[LINE_NUMBER]
                               WHERE oO.[LINE_NUMBER] = hL.[LINE_NUMBER])
FROM [dbo].[JOB_HISTORY_LINE] hL
```

**The problem:** the above will stick the `SUM` of the items in `ORDER_ITEMS` in all the entries in `JOB_HISTORY_LINE`.  This isn't correct.

`JOB_HISTORY_LINE` just contains information for each `LINE_NUMBER` associated to an `ORDER_NUMBER`. Each item in `ORDER_ITEMS` has an associated `LINE_NUMBER` and `ORDER_NUMBER` that can be referenced through `JOB_HISTORY`, which contains the `ORDER_NUMBER`.

**The goal:** each line in `JOB_HISTORY_LINES` should show the associated `COUNT` of `SERIAL_NUMBERS` from the `ORDER_ITEMS` table.

Please help me straighten this out so I can learn why I'm screwing this up :)

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: No error.  Just not getting query results I'm looking for.  Each line in JOB_HISTORY_LINES should show the associated COUNT of SERIAL_NUMBERS from the ORDER_ITEMS table.

Comment: Why do you need to store this redundant calculation that will need to be constantly maintained?

Comment: @AaronBertrand All this data eventually gets cleared out once parsed.  This is for measuring efficiency of a system.

Comment: @AaronBertrand further more, ORDER_ITEMS is cleared several times over, long before the histories are ever parsed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps what you are looking for is a correlated subquery:

```
UPDATE hL
    SET hL.[QUANTITY_COMPLETED] = (SELECT COUNT([SERIAL_NUMBER])
                                   FROM [dbo].[ORDER_ITEMS] oO INNER JOIN
                                        [dbo].[JOB_HISTORY] jH
                                        ON jH.[ORDER_NUMBER] = Oo.[ORDER_NUMBER]
                                   WHERE oO.[LINE_NUMBER] = hL.[LINE_NUMBER]
                                  )
    FROM [dbo].[JOB_HISTORY_LINE] hL;
```

Comment: Really nice.  Dang I was close.  Frusterating!  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE [hL]
SET [hL].[QUANTITY_COMPLETED]=[oo].[Total]
FROM [dbo].[JOB_HISTORY_LINE] [hL]
LEFT JOIN
 (
 SELECT [oO].[LINE_NUMBER]
       ,Count([SERIAL_NUMBER]) AS [Total]
 FROM [dbo].[ORDER_ITEMS] AS [oO]
 INNER JOIN [dbo].[JOB_HISTORY] AS [jH]
       ON [jH].[ORDER_NUMBER]=[Oo].[ORDER_NUMBER]
 INNER JOIN [dbo].[JOB_HISTORY_LINE] AS [hL]
       ON [hL].[LINE_NUMBER]=[oO].[LINE_NUMBER]
 GROUP BY [oO].[LINE_NUMBER]
 ) AS [OO]
 ON [oO].[LINE_NUMBER]=[hL].[LINE_NUMBER];
```